# how to change the process name of a Java application

Tags: java, windows, process, taskmanager

when executing a Java application the process name given to it is usually java.exe or javaw.exe. But how can I make it be called by the name of my application in window.
I can't use http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ because I want to run this jar on server.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The solution to your **actual** problem, might be as simple as writing a shell script with your _required process name_. To be clear, I didn't get the part about the application name in the Window. Is this a Swing application?

Comment: simple (but dumb) answer: "copy java.exe myappname.exe"

Comment: Why does running the JAR on a server mean you can't use launch4j?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy your java.exe as customName.exe (and put it in the same location where your java.exe is) and run your program as

`customName com.something.something.MyClass`
instead of
`java com.something.something.MyClass`

Comment: I have a jar file I am not running any class file. To start my jar i am using command :> java -jar jarname.jar

Comment: @Khoyendra, in that case you can type as `customName -jar jarname.jar`

Comment: But I want to run same jar two times with two different name.

Comment: @Khoyendra, make one more copy of java.exe (e.g, customName2.exe) and run your 2nd process with this exe (e.g, customName2 -jar jarName.jar)
And, you can have _n_ number of such copies of java.exe as per your requirement (my requirement was also exactly same as yours and for me this solution worked very well)

Comment: which java.exe file I need to update because java/jdk and java/jre contains nos of java.exe file. I tried after change the jre's java.exe file but it was showing "'customName' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Khoyendra, that you need to figur it out which jdk/jre installation you are using. Try to follow all the paths configured in PATH variable. (on linux you can find it by _which java_ command. But for windows there is no such utility - atleast I am aware of)

Answer (score 2):

make exe with [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) , that provide you option to create separate process

Comment: I doesn't want to install any setup, I want a windows command that will start my jar with another name, this setup can't help me.